# PDO code is not working properly

Tags: mysql, pdo

I changed my msql code to PDO but nothing is displayed can someone help me

when I go to the php page I get a blank page nothing is echoed /displayed can someone tell me what is wrong thank you

here is my PDO code

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sell_table WHERE ids=:ids");
$stmt->bindValue(':ids',$_GET['ids'] ,  PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            echo $row['names'].' '.$row['prices'];
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: _I get a fatal error_ - Ok, and what _is_ the error?

Comment: sorry I changed my code but now I don't get any errors I had id instead of ids ids is the name of my id

Comment: i just get a blank page

Comment: A blank page in PHP is usually a symptom of a 500 - Server error. Look at your server error log and find out what the error is.

Comment: before i changed id to ids i got this error                    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'' in /home/supersel/public_html/blue.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /home/supersel/public_html/blue.php(6): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM s...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/supersel/public_html/blue.php on line 6

Answer (score 0):

If you showed your code as it is your problem is that you're fetching the resultset into a variable named `$rows` but trying to echo from `$row`. You should've iterated over the `$rows` array.

Change

```php
echo $row['names'].' '.$row['prices'];
```

with something like

```php
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['names'].' '.$row['prices'];
}
```